Chord to a parabola given its midpoint
I know that if there is a parabola $y^2=4ax$ and $P(x_1,y_1)$ is the midpoint, and
$$S_1 = y_1^2 - 4ax_1,\>\>\>\>\>T = yy_1 + 2a(x+x_1)$$
and equating $T=S_1$ gives the equation of the chord of contact. But if my parabola is of the form, say

$(y+a)^2 = 4a(x+b)$
$(x+a)^2 = 4a(y+b)$

What would the respective chords be?

I don't think that equating $T=S_1$ gives the equation of the chord of contact.

I think this is what is meant,

With a general parabola in the focus/directrix form $$s=((x-x_F)^2+(y-y_F)^2)(a^2+b^2)-(a x+b y+ c)^2 =\
a^2 x_F^2 - 2 a^2 x_F x + a^2 y_F^2 - 2 a^2 y_F y + a^2 y^2 - 2 a b x y - 2 a c x +\ b^2 x_F^2 - 2 b^2 x_F x + b^2 y_F^2 - 2 b^2 y_F y + b^2 x^2 - 2 b c y - c^2=0$$
of the equation it’s still the joachimsthal formalism: $s_1=s_{11}.$

Or explicitly $$a^2 x_F^2 - a^2 x_F (x+x_1) + a^2 y_F^2 - a^2 y_F (y+y_1) + a^2 yy_1 - a b (x y_1 + y x_1) - a c (x+x_1) +\ b^2 x_F^2 - b^2 x_F (x+x_1) + b^2 y_F^2 - b^2 y_F (y+y_1) + b^2 xx_1 - b c (y+y_1) - c^2=\((x_1-x_F)^2+(y_1-y_F)^2)(a^2+b^2)-(a x_1+b y_1+ c)^2$$

$T=S_1$ does not give the equation of the chord of contact. For example, for $(a,x_1,y_1)=(1,10,2)$, the equation of the chord of contact is $y=x-8$, but $T=S_1$ gives $y=-x-28$ which does not have any intersection point with $y^2=4x$.

@mathlove Agreed, $s_1=s_{11}$ is not the chord of contact, but the chord of the parabola with the given point as its midpoint. Of course this assumes the point is inside. The points outside are the points for which the chord of contact have meaning over the reals. For the points on the parabola, both concepts agree with the tangent.

Maybe $T$ should be $yy_1 \color{red}- 2a(x+x_1)$ instead of $yy_1 \color{red}+ 2a(x+x_1)$.
